# Is there a way to get a tab key on an iPhone XR (iOS 12.4)?

Tags: iphone, ios

Can this be done, and if so how?

I am not seeking merely a solution that allows the input of a tab character, for example using voice; I'm asking for a way to make a tab key appear on the keyboard on the screen.

Example of need: on a chat site I go to, you can type the first few characters of another user's name and then tab to complete...or at least you can if you have got a tab key.

Another example of utility is to jump from box to box when completing an online form.

Comment: Have you looked into the vast selection of 3rd party keyboards available on the app store?

Comment: I've looked at some, but not yet found one that is described as coming with a tab key.

Comment: More out of curiosity – where would you use that? Online forms? VNC remote control?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83302/how-to-type-a-tab-character-on-an-iphone

Comment: @n1000 - My big current irritation with not having it is on a chat site I go to where you can type the first few characters of another user's nick and then tab to complete. But jumping between boxes on online forms too, yes.

Comment: @SteveChambers - Yes. I'm asking specifically about a key, not just how to input the character.

Comment: I see, thanks. Maybe you add that info to your question for a bit more clarity.